Are carbon fiber parts riveted, screwed or bolted?
For aircrafts made of composite material like carbon fiber, whats the right fastener method to attach the different aircrafts parts?

Generally bonded, bolted or riveted using steel shank with swaged collar type rivets like HI-SHEAR/HI-LITE. You can't use aluminum against carbon due to galvanic incompatibility.
I believe the 787 structure is largely bonded. On the other hand the A-220/C Series, which has carbon wings, uses swaged-collar steel rivets to attach the carbon parts like ribs, spars and skins together as if the wing was aluminum.

... also called "black aluminum" in the trade. Painful to look at when you know composites.

if they are mostly bonded, how do they un-bond when there is need to detach a part(i.e. access area for mechanic inspection)? is it more complicated than a rivet/bolt/screw?

ok so that means the bonding is only done on parts/areas where there is never going to be a need to detach the part(i.e. for inspection)?  In other areas rivets and bolts are used, correct?

@Gabe you figure that out going in, and if you need to detach or get access,  you design for removal using fasteners. Otherwise the bonded assemblies are permanent.

@Gabe With the poor long-term strength of aluminium, certain habits have formed which are rational when you deal with an aluminium structure, but irrational when composites are used. Composites now get punished for the poor experiences we made with aluminium in the past.
